# Dual of $C[0,1]$ separable space

Tags: functional-analysis

Is the dual of $C[0,1]$ a separable space? I know $C[0,1]$ is separable using the Weierstrass theorem, but I'm lost when talking about the dual. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Do you know what the dual is? At least it contains all point valuations: $f \to f(p)$ for any $p \in [0,1]$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The dual of $C[0,1]$ is not separable. The dual space consists of Borel  measures and the norm is the total variation norm. Consider the set $\{\delta_x: 0\leq x \leq 1\}$. This set is uncountable any two points are separated by distance $2$ so the dual space is not separable. [Here $\delta_x$ denotes the delta measure at $x$]

Comment: Why does the dual space consist of Borel measures? Isn't the dual space the set of bounded linear functionals?

Comment: @NoppaweeApichonpongpan Dual of $C([01])$ with the sup norm is  a very basic result in FA called Riesz Representation Theorem. You can refer to Rudin's RCA for a proof.